# Vue 3 event weird behaviour

Tags: vuejs3

Hello I have simple component where I try to do validation. Idea is simple check on fly if field value is empty or not, and send correct information about field like is field valid or not. Parent component receive event and can process this information. What go wrong is a situation when I write some text, then I delete everything and start typing again the first letter is not visible (like cut off). Value is updating from second letter.
I don't have any idea why this happen.

InputComponent:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label
      :for="props.id || `${props.name}Input`"
      class="form-label"
      :class="{ 'form-label--required': props.required }"
      v-if="props.label"
    >
      {{ props.label }}
    </label>
    <input
      class="form-control mb-2"
      type="text"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      :id="props.id || `${props.name}Input`"
      :placeholder="props.label"
      :name="props.name"
      :required="props.required"
      :min="props.min"
      :max="props.max"
      :value="props.modelValue"
      :class="{
        'is-invalid': !!errorMessage,
      }"
      @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
      @input="validate"
    />
    <div class="invalid-feedback mb-3" v-if="!!errorMessage">
      {{ errorMessage }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
};
</script>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed, defineEmits, defineProps, reactive } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  label: {
    type: String,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  required: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  validationMessage: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  min: {
    type: [String, null, undefined],
    default: null,
  },
  max: {
    type: [String, null, undefined],
    default: null,
  },
});

const emits = defineEmits(['update:modelValue', 'isValid']);

const validation = reactive({
  isValid: false,
  message: '',
});

const errorMessage = computed(() => {
  return Array.isArray(props.validationMessage)
    ? props.validationMessage[0]
    : props.validationMessage || validation.message;
});

const validate = (event: Event) => {
  const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

  if (props.required) {
    if (target.value) {
      validation.isValid = true;
      validation.message = '';
    } else {
      validation.isValid = false;
      validation.message = 'This field is required.';
    }

    emits('isValid', validation.isValid);
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@change` on a text `<input>` only fires when the value is changed **and** after it loses focus.  Unless you type into the input element and then click away, your parent component `v-model` and subsequently `props.modelValue` is never actually updating.

The "cut off" issue your seeing is due to Vue updating the DOM based on the validation message needing to be removed from the screen and during this update Vue is also updating `:value` to the latest value of `props.modelValue` which is empty making it look like the first character is not going through.

The solution is to do everything on `@input` which is the correct event for updating v-model *and* doing eager validation

```html
<input
      class="form-control mb-2"
      type="text"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      :id="props.id || `${props.name}Input`"
      :placeholder="props.label"
      :name="props.name"
      :required="props.required"
      :min="props.min"
      :max="props.max"
      :value="props.modelValue"
      :class="{
        'is-invalid': !!errorMessage,
      }"
      @input="validate"
    />
```

```js
const validate = (event: Event) => {
  const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  // always update v-model
  emits("update:modelValue", target.value);

  if (props.required) {
    if (target.value) {
      validation.isValid = true;
      validation.message = "";
    } else {
      validation.isValid = false;
      validation.message = "This field is required.";
    }

    emits("isValid", validation.isValid);
  }
};
```